# Application pool randomly crashes and stops for ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, stack-overflow

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API running on IIS. We come across an issue that the application pool crashes randomly and stops itself.

I tried to get dump file in order to check what is problem. When I add dump file to Visual Studio and "Debug with managed only", it shows that an error occurred at the end of some middleware code:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IConfiguration configuration)
{
   ...
   ...
   // Move to next delegate/middleware in the pipleline
   await next.Invoke(httpContext);
}
```

Error is :

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD24560085 in w3wp.exe.86340.dmp: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000000, 0x000000C04DD033F0).

I couldn't find any way to handle this, I have other middleware modules too, and they exit with the same code

Comment: It's almost certainly not the middleware. You have a stack overflow somewhere. Try examining your code for recursive functions.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary is it possible to find where this recursive function is from dump file, wtack trace shows this line of code, but where to find real error?